# Get what PLCameraView is showing on 3.0

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

with fw 2.2 i was able to get a screenshot using the private method _createCGImageRefRepresentationInFrame of UIWindow. In 3.0 doesn't exist anymore.

I used that method with the PLCameraView over a window to take a small video just by get as much screenshot as possible. Now i tried with the CALayer of the PLPreviewView and -renderInContext: method, but it always render the view as it has the iris closed.

How can i take a screenshot of what the cameraView is showing?

Thanks
Marco

Comment: Now there's a surprise, a private method that stopped working…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try for following code snippet to get

```
CGImageRef imageRef = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] _createDefaultImageSnapshot];
UIImage* img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];

//Now you can save it the way you want
//May as following
//oops yes this image is just the screenshot so better take care of unwanted image side
//So cut crap out from the image captured
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img, nil, nil, nil);
```